# How to use two different vuetify versions for two different vue instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have got strange requirement that i have to maintain two different vuetify versions for two different instances. (Process of angular to vue migration)

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Vuetify2 from 'vuetify2'

window.initOld = function () => {
  Vue.use(Vuetify)

  let vueObj = new Vue({
   el: 'old-app',
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
  })
  return vueObj
}

window.initNew = function () => {
  Vue.use(Vuetify2)

  let vueObj = new Vue({
   el: 'new-app',
   vuetify: new Vuetify2(),
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
  })
  return vueObj
}
```

I am retaining old pages with old version of vuetify1.x which has its own instance. In the same way i created new instance for the latest version of vuetify2.x which i created a new page.

Old pages are working fine with old instance and same case for the new pages as well. But the problem is if i come from old page to new page or vice versa, in this case its generated vuetify errors in console. I think its because of Vue.use() in both old and new instances.

Is there any way that i can use maintain two different versions of vuetify for two different vue instances? I fallowed this procedure to maintain two different versions of vuetify, if there is any other procedure please suggest.